# git: permissions only being applied with execute bit: can it be done without?

Tags: git

I'm having problems setting permissions on files with git. I'd like to make all files in the repository 644. When I first `clone` the repo, the files are a mix of different permissions:

```sh
-rw------- 1 username group   2305 Oct 25 15:16 addquotes.sas
-rw------- 1 username group    675 Oct 25 15:16 ama_permission.sas
-rw------- 1 username group   1581 Oct 25 15:16 append_words.sas
-rwx------ 1 username group   3688 Oct 25 15:16 sasv9_u8.cfg
-rwx------ 1 username group   1489 Oct 25 15:16 backtest/bt_means.sas
-rwx------ 1 username group    490 Oct 25 15:16 backtest/correct_vname.sas
-rwx------ 1 username group    838 Oct 25 15:16 backtest/gen_random_samples.sas
```

To attempt to fix this, I run `find . -type f | xargs chmod 644`. This changes the permissions on the file system, but only a few appear as modified when I do a `git status`:

```sh
        modified:   sasv9_u8.cfg
        modified:   backtest/bt_means.sas
        modified:   backtest/correct_vname.sas
        modified:   backtest/gen_random_samples.sas
```

Digging deeper, I noticed that the files showing as modified had the owner execute bit set. If I run `find . -type f | xargs chmod 744` (`744` vs `644`, to set the owner execute bit), then all the files appear in the `git status` command.

Is there any way to get git to recognize the permission without setting the execute bit on the owner? This behavior seems odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two points worth mentioning :

- `git` does not store the whole range of unix permissions on files : it only stores "regular files" and "executable files",
- `git` behaves like a normal  process, and doesn't try to go around your [umask](https://askubuntu.com/a/44548/18501) ; the reason why you see no access rights for the `group` or `other` part is probably because your umask is set to `0077`

A "regular file" will be checked out as `-rw-rw-rw-` -- minus your umask ; an "executable file" will be checked out as `-rwxrwxrwx` -- again, minus your umask.

---

About what you see :

- my guess is that your umask is set to `0077` (no rights for `group` and `other`), so the "regular files" get checked out as `-rw-------` and "executable files" as `-rwx------`
- if you run `chmod 644` on your files, `git` detects that files that were previously executable are not executable anymore, and these ones show up,
- I'm surprised that setting `chmod 744` makes `git` detect a change on "executable" files : on my machine, it looks like `git` only checks for the (linux) executable flag set for `user` to determine if a file should be stored as executable ; detecting a change on "regular files" is expected.

---

How to "fix" this :

- perhaps there is a reason why your umask is so restrictive, so perhaps the situation you have is the correct one ;
- if your umask is too restrictive : choose a way to set it to a suitable value ;
- to "fix" existing files : as @torek suggested the easiest way is probably to use the `X` option of chmod, which will set the executable flag only if at least one executable flag is set :

```
# you seem to want to give rw (and possibly x) access to the group :
chmod -R g+rwX *
# perhaps r (and possibly x) to "others" :
chmod -R o+rX *
```

Comment: TIL. Thank you - git permissions had always confused me, because of seeing changes in the `modified` list of `git status`.

Comment: Best to set the umask first, but for fixing afterwards, most modern `chmod`s support the +X option, so that you can run `chmod -R +rX backtest` for instance.